# Forms in fancybox or full size page - which is good for conversions?

Tags: forms, responsive-design, conversion

I have a responsive website, with a Sign Up form & a Contact form.

I'm not able to decide whether should I open these forms in fancybox / prettyphoto or redirect user to a full sized page with form?

Which is good for more conversions?

I found forms that are open in iframe  using fancybox / prettyphoto difficult to fill on mobiles...

Pls advise.